# PayPal JSON format updating order

Tags: json, rest, paypal

I know I am close on this, the error messages are getting nicer.  Currently, I can call a similar call to update the seller's email no issue via Postman currently, working on updating the amount and associated objects. Something in my request format is off.

Is my breakdown section in the correct location?  The amount_breakdown documentation looks like it is on same level as value and currency_code, so does it need to move into that section.

Here's my request JSON via Postman:

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
        "value": {
            "currency_code": "CAD",
            "value": "2",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "CAD",
                "value": "2",
                "breakdown": {
                    "item_total": {
                        "currency_code": "CAD",
                        "value": "2"
                    },
                    "tax_total": {
                        "value": "0",
                        "currency_code": "CAD"
                    }
                }
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "First Product Name",
                    "description": "Optional descriptive text..",
                    "unit_amount": {
                        "currency_code": "CAD",
                        "value": "2"
                    },
                    "tax": {
                        "value": "0",
                        "currency_code": "CAD"
                    },
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount/breakdown/item_total",
            "location": "body",
            "issue": "ITEM_TOTAL_REQUIRED",
            "description": "If item details are specified (items.unit_amount and items.quantity) corresponding amount.breakdown.item_total is required."
        }
    ],
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "acecd3643c994",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ITEM_TOTAL_REQUIRED",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Different variations of objects.
I can get the other PATCH operation working no issue but it is much simpler in object structure

Answer (score 0):

There should be no `amount` key under the /amount path, and the `items` array does not belong at that /amount path either.

Comment: Hi Preston, thanks very much for your help! I managed to get it working with the following code just a few minutes ago: [{"op":"replace","path":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'","value":{"amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1","breakdown":{"item_total":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1"}}},"invoice_id":"123456","items":[{"name":" Shampoo","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1"},"quantity":"1","sku":"132"},{"name":"Shipping costs","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"0"},"quantity":"1"}]}}]. Cheers!